# Why is “definitely” so frequently typoed?

Tags: orthography

*Definitely* seems to be one of the most frequently typoed words in written English on the Internet, enough to bring somebody to create [d-e-f-i-n-i-t-e-l-y.com](http://www.d-e-f-i-n-i-t-e-l-y.com/).

<s>Simon</s> Google says, in a completely unscientific manner:

1. `defini tely` ×105,000,000 (43.4%)
2. `defina tely` ×  80,000,000 (33.0%)
3. `define t ly` ×  21,900,000 (  9.0%)
4. `defina t ly` ×  18,300,000 (  7.6%)
5. `defi ant ly` ×  15,900,000 (  6.6%)¹
6. `definant ly` ×       858,000 (    .4%)
7. `definent ly` ×       217,000 (    .1%)

Why is this the case? What are the reasons behind these misspellings? Are those mistakes limited to the Internet, or are they also present in handwritten English as well?

<sup>1</sup>Defiantly [actually is a word](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/defiantly), so that obviously skews the numbers.

Comment: Why the close vote? Question seems OK to me.

Comment: The question seems subjective and argumentative; it's not possible to know the reason why somebody doesn't correctly write a word, especially when it's not well identified the referenced group. The reported statistics don't identify who wrote each of the words (a person who speaks Chinese as first language, instead of any Romance language).

Comment: @kiamlaluno: actually, I think the most misspellings come from native speakers. PS: If you're positive there is no way to know, then "there is no way to know" is an answer.

Comment: I think that also non native speakers have the problem of misspelled words; the reason why a native speaker doesn't correctly write a word is different from the reason a non native speaker does the same mistake. For example, I noted that for three time in row I wrote _backing_ when I meant _baking_; I would not have the problem with _definitively_ because probably I am pronouncing it with an _|æ|_ sound (as the first _a_ in apple).

Comment: This one has bothered me forever.  It seems to percolate, uncorrected, among young tech types.

Comment: I think this is a really valid question.  Kiamlaluno, if you look at it that way, there is 'No way to know' lots of other questions too.  Perhaps it could have been better targeted/phrased...but it's a totally valid point/question, people DO mis-spell that word a LOT.

Comment: @Jared It's okay, the close votes expired a long time ago.

Comment: There is a significant difference between a spelling mistake and a typo.  In the first case, the writer does not know how to spell a word correction, while in the second case, they know how to spell it but have fumbled-fingered their keys.  I think you should not have called it a typo.  It’s that people know no better, which is something altogether different as being a careless typist.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*Definitely* is pronounced as `[dɛfɪnətli]`, where the `[ə]` indicates a schwa sound. A schwa could easily be any vowel in English, so it’s easy to misspell it.

Comment: I rarely have trouble with spelling, but one word which always makes me stop to think is *parallelepiped*.  It’s that second *e* that does it: it’s pronounced as a schwa, and could reasonably be any vowel apart from *u*.  And to top it off, the analogy with *parallelogram* misleadingly suggests *o*...

Comment: To spell *parallelepiped*, I use this analysis: parallel+epi+ped ... "epi" meaning "upon" and "ped" meaning "foot"

Comment: Also, the final E is not pronounced, and “definantly” and “definently” arise because some accents have epenthetic [n] in *-ately* words (→ *-antly*).

Answer (score 10):

Can you think of any other words that end in *-itely* that are pronounced the same? I think the majority of them end in *-ately*, e.g. *alternately*, *indiscriminately*, *fortunately*, *intimately*. Therefore, people uninterested in spelling irregularity will intuitively spell it “definately” because it seems more plausible if you don’t know better.

Edit: Just thought of one: *infinitely*... but it’s definitely rarer!

Comment: Infinitely is easier to spell because it isn't pronounced infinately, even though definitely is often pronounced definately.

Comment: @Umang: Evidence? As far as I know, "definitely" is pronounced with a schwa sound for its third vowel, it's never pronounced with a stressed vowel there of any kind.

Comment: _Infinitely_ is pronounced _|ˈɪnfənətli|_, at least in American English.

Comment: No, I meant how it is usually pronounced, not how it should be pronounced. And I'm still probably maybe wrong.

Comment: @Umang: In American English, *infinitely* can be pronounced either /ˈɪnfənətli/ or /ˈɪnfənɪtli/ (same for *definitely*). See the [American Heritage Dictionary](http://education.yahoo.com/reference/dictionary/entry/definite). It all depends on your exact dialect. If you have a schwa in *definitely* but not *infinitely*, that would definitely confuse you.

Comment: When I think of the word "definitely", what comes to mind is the over-the-top stress-every-syllable pronunciation that Jim Dale uses in the Harry Potter audio book series. How would you do that with the [dɛfɪnətli] pronunciation? If you wanted to stress the ə, would you pronounce it as eɪ or ɪə? If the former, then the definately spelling makes a bit more sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

Believe it or not, the phenomenon you describe is as much a function of readership as of authorship. That means that its occurrence has mostly to do with *where* one finds the word *definitely*, however it happens to be spelled.

Furthermore, the OP’s mistaken use of *typo* as a verb — which it is not — is revealing of how the Internet has become a great leveller between more literacy and less literacy — that is, between advanced spellers and formative ones.

That, in a nutshell, answers the question.

Imagine that all “literate” grade levels, the ones after the first grade, could be lumped together and given the same spelling quiz. No matter whether the answers were oral, printed, cursive, or typed, would you expect any “better” (that is, more skewed) a distributrion of correct and incorrect spellings as is shown in the OP table? “Definitely” no? Or “defunutly” [*sic*] yes?

An interesting aspect of the table’s spellings of *definitely*  is that they seem to reveal differences in hearing perceptions and hence pronunciations, which suggests a possibility that they might be influenced by ear-nose-and-throat (otorhinolaryngological) influences, especially otic and nasal.

Comment: An ENT doc would probably find it interesting to compare such a misspelling distribution as in the OP, with a similar distribution of nasal and otic syndromes amoung an English speaking population sample

Comment: I’ve tried to whip your posting into some vague semblance of readability.  You use too many long sentences, too many parens, too many diversions and breaks, for it to make any sense.  You also need more paragraphs. And ironically enough, a spellchecker: you got *its*, *occurrence*, and *otorhinolaryngological* all wrong.  If you feel my copyedit has unravelled your post, please feel free to make amends.  I’m only trying to help. Also, if you wish to comment on your own post instead of answering another commenter, often it is best to edit it and put the comment there, not in the comments field.

Comment: The edits and commentary are too unfocused for a practical reply addressing the proofs and points made, and what seems an inappopriate, non constructive tone taken. So, no offense intended--it is the only recourse provided--I am compelled to return an unconstructive flag. I will look for a way, for you and other's edification, to make responses and suggestons related to fine art of proofing/editing on meta. If it doesn't appear soon, its just that time comes at a premium for me. Understanding is appreciated.

Comment: the original post along with much of its meaning has been obliterated...to that a discussion on meta has been foreclosed to all practical purposes. Please return the original answer for me to copy, and publish for discussion on meta. Then once I have recovered my essay, if you like, I will request deletion of my entire answer.

Comment: Click the “18 hours ago” link: all previous versions are available.

Comment: never mind, thanks for the edit. disregard any flag that did not fail to upload.